# Is there an easy way to increase the width of the list of options for a custom field in the pull down?

Tags: custom-fields

We have a custom field that has a number of options.  The descriptions of a few of them are long and wrap funny in the pull down, which, sigh, apparently is confusing to some people.  Is there an easy change the width of this pull down?

Comment: Is it a Select2 list?

Comment: It is a Select2 list

Comment: Perhaps this discussion of widening Select2 elements might help: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/setting-select2-widths

Comment: I suspect it might.  But, at least for me, dealing with style sheets is not easy, so I think the answer is no, there isn't an easy way.  In the meantime, I convinced the user to shorten descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ended up needing to figure this out. So in a file mysite.css I put this:

```
#select2-drop {width: 350px !important;}
```

Then in Administer => System Settings => Resource URL, I put the path and file name the file in the Custom css URL.  (All the other places to put URLs on the page want just a directory.  Custom css URL also needs the file name.)